# What changes should i make in my build.gradle before releasing my android app to production

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

This is more of asking suggestion for changes to be made to my build.gradle as i am about to release my first android app.Searched a lot but no satisfactory solution.Here is my gradle file

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
}
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}


android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.app"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 25
    multiDexEnabled true
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    resConfigs "en_US", "hi_IN"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
}

}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile('com.digits.sdk.android:digits:2.0.6@aar') {
    transitive = true;

}
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.7@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
compile('io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.3.10@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:10.2.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:10.2.1'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.2.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:10.2.1'
compile ('io.branch.sdk.android:library:2.5.9') {
    transitive = true;
    exclude module: 'answers-shim';
}

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Every suggestion matters as it could also be helpful for other beginners like me who are planning to release their first build in play store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see that you have enabled pro guard in your release mode. I suggest you to consider following statement from android doc

For even more code shrinking, try the `proguard-android-optimize.txt` file that's in the same location. It includes the same ProGuard rules, but with other optimizations that perform analysis at the bytecode level—inside and across methods—to reduce your APK size further and help it run faster.

change this

`proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro`'

to this

```
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('**proguard-android-optimize.txt**'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
```

Also add this to release mode

```
shrinkResources true
```

And don't forget to add pro guard rules if you haven't already.

Doing above two things will make your app small in size and more optimized.

Comment: pro guard rules? how to define them in my file.

Comment: @Shubhendra you need to define them in proguard-rules.pro file for your app. If you don't know about them already, you need to read about them. here is link to proguard official manual. https://www.guardsquare.com/en/proguard/manual/usage. And mark my answer as accepted if it helped.

Comment: Got it @v4_adi, and i also checked the firebase documentation regarding pro guard rules.Cheers:-)